# ajax call in js not firing

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following code to retrieve data from MySQL. The following test suggests that something is wrong with the ajax part because the 'ttt' alert does not execute. What am I missing?

```
function autoFill() {
    var claimantIDs = document.getElementById('claimant_search').value;
    alert(claimantIDs);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_claim.php",
        data: {ID, claimantIDs},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert("ttt");
        }
    });

    alert("END");
}
```

the relevant php is:

```
<?php

    require_once('../dbconnect.php');

    $ID = $_POST['ID'];

    $result = mysql_query("select *  from 1tbl_CLAIMANT_DETAIL  where ID = '".$ID."' ") or die(mysql_error());

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $data = json_encode($row);

    echo $data;

?>
```

Comment: try adding the error function to see what could be causing the failure.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: look at your browser console for errors.

Comment: probably also helps to see what get_claim.php is doing with that POST

Answer (score 1):

In your AJAX part, look at the way you are passing value through POST method

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "get_claim.php",
                    data: {ID, claimantIDs},// <-- problem
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){
                            alert("ttt");
                    }
            });
```

data field in AJAX required a JSON object which should be key value pair, but you are directly passing the value and I assume that due to this your PHP code is not able to get the values that's why your code is not running properly. You should also inlcude the error method inside you AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

In your ajax code way your data passing is wrong I think.

Please try this 
**data: {ID: claimantIDs},** 
in your ajax code segment .

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug your get_claim.php file by printing $_REQUEST variables like this at the top of your file

```
    <?php
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
    ?>
```

If you are able to see the data which you passed by ajax then your ajax is working fine. Also check into network, weather the url is hitting properly or not.

Comment: sure thing thnx

Comment: finally got to the problem. did alt-shift-I in firefox and got 'ReferenceError: $ is not defined'. searched the internet for the right links and finally it worked. Thnx everyone, the json format was also an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here. 
`{ID, claimantIDs},`

Change it to `{'ID' : claimantIDs},`

Also, Change `mysql to mysqli` as `mysql` is deprecated version. You will not be able to use it in the latest PHP versions.